# Serial no condition in vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

i am getting one object and iterating it to display in table.
Now the table is as shown below.

[image: before]

```
<tr v-for="(cover,index) in  packetDocument" i = index>
  <td align="center">{{index+1}}</td>
  <td align="center">{{cover.docFile}}</td>
  <td align="center">{{cover.docType}}</td>
  <td align="center" colspan="2">{{cover.docDesc}}</td>
</tr>
```

since column 1 belongs to same category i would like to display serial number like this,

[image: after]

please tell me how to proceed in this.

Comment: Are the records already sorted by TypeN ?

Comment: yes. No need to sort records. They are sorted.

Comment: You might want to regroup your data based on the `type`. So maybe have a multidimensional array that's grouped by their type then only print out the `index` if it's the first one in the inner arrays

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Use a variable like `sNum` (see example below) to store the serial.
- Retrieve the number out of `docType` using a small regexp
- Create a Vue `method` to return the `sNum` into the View when needed:

```js
var sNum = -1;

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    packetDocument: [
      {docFile:"trz", docType:"type1", docDesc:"def"},
      {docFile:"fgh", docType:"type1", docDesc:"jhj"},
      {docFile:"eze", docType:"type2", docDesc:"oiu"},
      {docFile:"cvb", docType:"type2", docDesc:"tzz"},
      {docFile:"vbn", docType:"type7", docDesc:"rtz"},
      {docFile:"vbn", docType:"type7", docDesc:"rew"}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    serialNum: function(cover) {
      var n = cover.docType.replace(/\D/g, '');
      if (sNum !== n) {
        sNum = n;
        return sNum
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <table>

    <tr v-for="(cover,index) in  packetDocument" i=index>
      <td align="center">{{serialNum(cover)}}</td>
      <td align="center">{{cover.docFile}}</td>
      <td align="center">{{cover.docType}}</td>
      <td align="center" colspan="2">{{cover.docDesc}}</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
```